# Custom Omniauth 'Authentication failure! csrf_detected'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth

I'm trying to create a custom Omniauth for [Smartrecruiters API](https://dev.smartrecruiters.com) OAuth 2.0

omniauth.rb

```
module OmniAuth
  module Strategies   
   class SmartRecruiters < OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2
    option :name, 'smart_recruiters'
    option :client_options, {
      site: 'https://www.smartrecruiters.com',
      authorize_url: '/identity/oauth/allow',
    }

    def request_phase
     super
    end

    def authorize_params
      super.tap do |params|
        %w[scope client_options].each do |v|
          if request.params[v]
            params[v.to_sym] = request.params[v]
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and outside the module (in the same file):

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :smart_recruiters, {client_id}, {client_secret},
           scope: {scope},
           :setup => lambda {|env|
             site = "https://www.smartrecruiters.com/identity/oauth/allow"
             env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_options].site = site
           }
end
```

routes.rb

```
 match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'integrations#create', via: [:get,:post]
```

I'm getting this response:

```
ERROR (smart_recruiters) Authentication failure! csrf_detected: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, csrf_detected | CSRF detected
ERROR (smart_recruiters) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, csrf_detected | CSRF detected
FATAL
```

I read about disabling the CSRF using:
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: :create
in my controller, but it didn't change anything.

I'm using Rails 4.2.8 and Ruby 2.4.5p335.

Any suggestions?

Thanks